# Select a non-empty value for each column in each table in each database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, privacy

There might be a better way to do this. But I'm trying to find columns that might contain personal information.

Problem is that the tables are poorly named (non-english, abbreviations). So I'm running this dynamic script, that will return all tables in all databases and their columns.

```
USE master;
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)
SET @SQL=';WITH cteCols (dbName, colName) AS (SELECT NULL, NULL '
SELECT @SQL=@SQL+'UNION
SELECT
'''+d.name COLLATE Czech_CI_AS +'.''+sh.name COLLATE Czech_CI_AS +''.''+o.name COLLATE Czech_CI_AS  ''dbSchTab''
, c.name COLLATE Czech_CI_AS ''colName''
FROM ['+d.name+'].sys.columns   c 
    JOIN ['+d.name+'].sys.objects o ON c.object_id=o.object_id 
    JOIN ['+d.name+'].sys.schemas sh ON o.schema_id=sh.schema_id
WHERE o.[type] = ''U'' COLLATE Czech_CI_AS'
FROM sys.databases d

SET @SQL = @SQL + ')
SELECT
    *
FROM cteCols cs
ORDER BY 1;'

EXEC (@SQL);
```

Result:

```
+---------------------+------------+
| DatabaseSchemaTable | ColumnName |
+---------------------+------------+
| dev1.dbo.Users      | Col1       |
| dev1.dbo.Users      | Col2       |
| dev1.dbo.Users      | Col3       |
| dev1.dbo.Users      | Col4       |
+---------------------+------------+
```

But because of the poor column naming, I can't tell what data is in these columns. I'd like to select a TOP (1) non NULL value from each column, but I'm struggling.

Required result:

```
+---------------------+------------+--------------+
| DatabaseSchemaTable | ColumnName | ColumnValue  |
+---------------------+------------+--------------+
| dev1.dbo.Users      | Col1       | 20           |
| dev1.dbo.Users      | Col2       | 2018-02-06   |
| dev1.dbo.Users      | Col3       | 202-555-0133 |
| dev1.dbo.Users      | Col4       | John Doe     |
+---------------------+------------+--------------+
```

Ideas I had:

- I would need to either transpose each of the tables (probably not a
  job for PIVOT)
- I could join with the table dynamically and only display the current column. But I can't use dynamic column in correlated subquery.

Any ideas?

Comment: So you want to try and understand what column contains what data, based on the first non-null value? seems to me like you are going into a world of pain. I mean, what if the value is 20? How can you tell 20 what, even if it is all just personal information - it could be a lot of things...

Comment: I mean the columns are not random giberish, but weird abbreviations. If i see a col name 'nmrtln' and value 202-555-0133 I could tell that it's a telephone number. It's not perfect, but it would help as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

You might try this:

```
--In this table we write our findings
CREATE TABLE ##TargetTable(ID INT IDENTITY, TableName VARCHAR(500), FirstRowXML XML);

--the undocumented sp "MSforeachtable" allows to create a statement where the 
--question mark is a place holder for the actual table
--(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM ? FOR XML PATH('row')) will create one single XML with all first row's values
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'INSERT INTO ##TargetTable(TableName,FirstRowXML) SELECT ''?'', (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM ? FOR XML PATH(''row''))';

--Now it is easy to get what you want
SELECT ID 
      ,TableName
      ,col.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') AS colname
      ,col.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS colval
FROM ##TargetTable
CROSS APPLY FirstRowXML.nodes('/row/*') A(col);

GO
DROP TABLE ##TargetTable
```

Just use `SELECT TOP X` to get more than one row...

### UPDATE

The following will create a table with all columns of all tables of all databases and fetch one value per row.

```sql
CREATE TABLE ##TargetTable(ID INT IDENTITY
                           ,TABLE_CATALOG VARCHAR(300),TABLE_SCHEMA VARCHAR(300),TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(300),COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(300)
                           ,DATA_TYPE VARCHAR(300),CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH INT, IS_NULLABLE VARCHAR(10),Command VARCHAR(MAX),OneValue NVARCHAR(MAX));
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb
'USE ?; 
INSERT INTO ##TargetTable(TABLE_CATALOG,TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE,CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,IS_NULLABLE,Command)
SELECT ''?''
      ,c.TABLE_SCHEMA
      ,c.TABLE_NAME
      ,c.COLUMN_NAME
      ,c.DATA_TYPE
      ,c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
      ,c.IS_NULLABLE
      , CASE WHEN c.IS_NULLABLE=''YES''
             THEN ''SELECT CAST(MAX('' + QUOTENAME(c.COLUMN_NAME) + '') AS NVARCHAR(MAX))'' 
             ELSE ''SELECT TOP 1 CAST('' + QUOTENAME(c.COLUMN_NAME) + '' AS NVARCHAR(MAX))''
        END
      + '' FROM '' + QUOTENAME(''?'') + ''.'' + QUOTENAME(c.TABLE_SCHEMA) + ''.'' + QUOTENAME(c.TABLE_NAME) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c 
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t ON c.TABLE_CATALOG=t.TABLE_CATALOG AND c.TABLE_SCHEMA=t.TABLE_SCHEMA AND c.TABLE_NAME=T.TABLE_NAME AND t.TABLE_TYPE=''BASE TABLE''
WHERE c.DATA_TYPE NOT IN(''BINARY'',''VARBINARY'',''IMAGE'',''NTEXT'')';

DECLARE @ID INT,@Command VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT ID,Command FROM ##TargetTable
OPEN cur;
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @ID,@Command;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
    SET @Command = 'UPDATE ##TargetTable SET OneValue=(' + @Command + ') WHERE ID=' + CAST(@ID AS VARCHAR(100))
    PRINT @command;
    EXEC(@Command);
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @ID,@Command;
END
CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;
GO
SELECT * FROM ##TargetTable;
GO
DROP TABLE ##TargetTable;
```

Comment: Thanks, somewhere I read about a problem with sp_Msforeachtable, but I can't remember what it was and cannot find it.
Edit: Also that works only for current database.

Comment: @Zikato, well, it's undcoumented so you cannot rely on it. This might be a draw back for a productive deployment. But it's perfectly okay for such a *one-time* job...

Comment: @Zikato If I get this correctly this is a *one-time-hack*. Are there just a few databases? Just type manually `USE SomeDb` and press F5, then `USE NextDb` and press F5... If there are very many DBs use a cursor... It doesn't matter if this is elegant or beautiful, correct ;-) ?

Comment: @Zikato See my update... I provide another approach using dynamic SQL and a cursor. Try it out.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a temporary table such as ##cols, and then use this temporary table to loop through the table, running update queries on the table itself. Mind you, we have a lot of spaces and other potentially troublesome characters in our field names. Therefore I updated your cte with some QUOTENAMEs around the field / table / schema / db names.

```
USE master;
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max);
SET @SQL=';WITH cteCols (dbName, colName, top1Value) AS (SELECT NULL, NULL, CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(MAX)) '
SELECT @SQL=@SQL+' UNION
SELECT
'''+QUOTENAME(d.[name]) COLLATE Czech_CI_AS +'.''+QUOTENAME(sh.name) COLLATE Czech_CI_AS +''.''+QUOTENAME(o.name) COLLATE Czech_CI_AS  ''dbSchTab''
, QUOTENAME(c.name) COLLATE Czech_CI_AS ''colName'', CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS ''top1Value''
FROM ['+d.[name]+'].sys.columns   c 
    JOIN ['+d.[name]+'].sys.objects o ON c.object_id=o.object_id 
    JOIN ['+d.[name]+'].sys.schemas sh ON o.schema_id=sh.schema_id
WHERE o.[type] = ''U'' COLLATE Czech_CI_AS'
FROM sys.databases d;

SET @SQL = @SQL + ')
SELECT
    *
INTO ##Cols
FROM cteCols cs
ORDER BY 1;'

EXEC (@SQL);

DECLARE @colName VARCHAR(255), @dbName VARCHAR(255), @SQL2 NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE C CURSOR FOR SELECT [colName],[dbName] FROM ##Cols;
    OPEN C;
    FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @colName, @dbName;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL2='UPDATE ##Cols SET [top1Value] = (SELECT TOP 1 x.'+@colName+' FROM '+@dbName+' x WHERE x.'+@colName+' IS NOT NULL) WHERE [colName]='''+@colName+''' AND [dbName]='''+@dbName+''''

        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL2
        FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @colName, @dbName
    END;
    CLOSE C;
DEALLOCATE C;

SELECT * FROM ##Cols;
```

It's not pretty, but it'd suit your needs.